# How to keep one column of information while feeding another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input file with two columns:

| county name | id |
| --- | --- |
| "York, SC" | GHCND:USW00053871 |

I use the id column to create a list. Then I have a loop for the id to make an online weather request.

```
input_file = "id_in_sample.csv"  
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)

list = df['id'].tolist()
```

Then I save the weather information along with the id as a csv file.

| id | weather |
| --- | --- |
| GHCND:USW00053871 | 5 |

I am trying to collect the county name in my file as well. So that it looks like the following table.

| county name | id | weather |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "York, SC" | GHCND:USW00053871 | 5 |

Is there a way to do it within the loop when I make a request or should I try to merge/join once I have the csv file?

Comment: not really getting your question. you can access country by `df.loc[df["id"] == id, "country"] ` inside the loop

Comment: can you add the expected output and rephrase your question a bit

Comment: @srinath Thank you for the comment. I edited the question with my expected output!

Comment: What is preventing you from having the 2 data sets in the form of dataframes and then merging them along the 'id' column?

Comment: As @Rip_027  suggested, keep the id and county name in one df and id and weather in another df. And merge based on id.

Comment: can you please share the sample code for computing weather.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input file (`id_in_sample.csv`) using pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "county name": ["York, SC"],
    "id": ["GHCND:USW00053871"]
})
```

As per your statement - `Then I save the weather information along with the id as a csv file.` the weather information is saved in another csv file. load the csv file using pandas

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ["GHCND:USW00053871"],
    "weather": [5]
})
```

now merge both the dataframes based on id

```
df.merge(df2, on=["id"], how="inner")
```

Sample result

```
  county name                 id  weather
0    York, SC  GHCND:USW00053871        5
```

if needed you can save the merged result back to csv file.

Note: Instead of reading the second dataframe (weather info) from file, you can compute the weather values , merge and then write to a file. but it completely depends on the usecase.

Comment: Thank you @srinath! I use `pd.merge` and it works!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101 - Before raising the question, do enough search. the link has a complete explanation of joins.